# Symfony 5 Registration Form validation not working

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony5

Im just learning Symfony for the first time.

The Form Validation is not working as expected, I have literally left the boiler plate code as per the Symfony docs, I have read other stack overflow articles and the docs 10 times to see if I have missed something, but I cant figure it out.

client-side validation has been switched off which works fine to test server side validation Basically.
But when the form is submitted, the isValid() method returns true even with an empty form as well as invalid data. I have added constraints in both the Entity and in the formType but it just bypasses everything, I know this for a fact, because the exceptions are being thrown by the database, or by the password encode method.

I have a simple code example below please check:

ps: This is a dummy project for learning,
Here is the code:

```
//App\Entity\MyFavorite.php

//App\Controller\RegistrationController:

<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\MyFavorite;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\
Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
    */
    public function register(
        Request $request,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,        
        ValidatorInterface $validator): Response
    {
        $user = new MyFavorite();
        $form = $this->createForm(
             RegistrationFormType::class, $user
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // encode the plain password
        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
            )
        );

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        // do anything else you need here, like send an email

        return $this->redirectToRoute('myfav_vault');
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}


//App\Entity\MyFavorite
<?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use App\Repository\MyFavoriteRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    //-> Bringing in the Validator Constraints as Assert
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MyFavoriteRepository::class)
     * @UniqueEntity(fields={"uniqueCode"},
       message="There is already an   account with this uniqueCode")
     */
    class MyFavorite implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=11, unique=true)
     * -> Adding my first custom assertion:
     * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]. {3}$/")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *    min = 11,
     *    max = 11
     * )
     */
    private $uniqueCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUniqueCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uniqueCode;
    }

    public function setUniqueCode(string $uniqueCode): self
    {
        $this->uniqueCode = $uniqueCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->uniqueCode;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
       //not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm insecurity.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user,    
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getExpiry(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->expiry;
    }

    public function setExpiry(?\DateTimeInterface $expiry): self
    {
        $this->expiry = $expiry;

        return $this;
    }
}    


//App\Form\RegistrationFormType
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\MyFavorite;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
//-> Getting basic TextType
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

//-> Testing out with Regex and String

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('uniqueCode')
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    //-> I am removing this as I do not want to provide options for min/max length
                    /*new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),*/
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => MyFavorite::class,
            //->Im going to turn of form validation on the client to see if the validation works on the server:
            'validation_groups' => false
        ]);
    }
}


//register.html.twig:




  {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for flashError in app.flashes('verify_email_error') %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ flashError }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <h1>Register</h1>
    
    {{ form_start(registrationForm, {'attr': {'novalidate':'novalidate'}}) }}
        {# This line had to be added manually so the form comes at the right place, some how all fields were not included #}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.name) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.uniqueCode) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
            label: 'Password'
        }) }}
        

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
    {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Findings:

When submitting a fully empty form:
encodePassword() throws an exception as password field is null and it expects string, (it should not even come to this stage as I imagine isValid() should return false?)

Submitting with a password and all the others as empty values:
Bypasses everything and only the database throws an exception.

Submitting wrong pattern for uniqueCode: The validator does not even recognise anything and passes it every time

The handleRequest() method is not throwing any exceptions or returning false except for the password where I get a very ugly error saying argument 2 for password cant be null,
So clearly the validation is not happening and the isValid() is returning true.

The error exceptions are coming from the database,

When I try to insert a unique code with the wrong pattern it gets inserted no problem,
When the name is blank it passes validation but the database throws an exception,
When the password field is empty it still passes validation,

the Symfony docs says:

the handleRequest() method writes data back to the same object,

Then we validate the data:

"In the previous section, you learned how a form can be submitted with valid or invalid data. In Symfony, the question isn’t whether the “form” is valid, but whether or not the underlying object ($task in this example) is valid after the form has applied the submitted data to it. Calling $form->isValid() is a shortcut that asks the $task object whether or not it has valid data."

I tried to look at the ValidatorInterface documentation, but there it clearly says:
"Most of the time, you won’t interact directly with the validator service or need to worry about printing out the errors. Most of the time, you’ll use validation indirectly when handling submitted form data. For more information, see how to validate Symfony forms."

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you use a buggy unclean spaghetti code framework?  Especially one that has been around for over ten years and is perhaps the most widely used framework out there?

Comment: Because I have just finished university and about to do a masters, I love PHP development, there are not many options yet, I still prefer Symfony to Laravel and Im building my own, I liked Symfony a lot, still do, but now Its just very frustrating when simple things that are supposed to work out of the box are not, I dont understand why the boiler plate code is failing, and what I am doing wrong,

Comment: Very open to learning it though and more than happy to take my comments back if I can be shown my mistakes, But from what I have seen, something as simple as form validation, should not be as complicated, I have tried to do everything the docs have mentioned, I have now removed those comments because it seems like some people take it personally or think its arrogant or not want to help me out, Its just my observation, Its not a clean framework

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use annotations as well as explicit constraints.  Hard to tell from the details you provided exactly what is going on.  And trying to trouble shoot this sort of problem based on what is posted to the database is particularly challenging.  Consider creating a new Symfony project, add one form with one property with validation.  Follow the docs as close as you can.  If you still have trouble then check your project into github and post a link.  But more than likely, if you take a break and start over with something simple then you will figure it out on your own.

Comment: This was happening before I added explicit constraints, them same problem continues, Its supposed to be a Registration form, Happy to start over and try again, I am also happy to upload to GitHub, I have not even really used GitHub properly, but Im happy to try this now, Its just that this is my dummy project and I have created lots of notes here

Comment: What details would you need? Happy to provide anything, thanks

Comment: Post whole contents of the form, entity and controller please

Comment: So sorry for the delay, I have added all three classes, the entity, the Registration form type and the Controller and the template, and I am doing what you suggested by starting over

Comment: By the way all the patterns and everything works perfectly from the client side, its only when I turn off client side validation, it fails on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the right format for Stackoverflow but we can see how far we can get before getting shut down.  Might need to continue on the Reddit Symfony forum.

Start small by getting this following action to work.  Note that there is no entity or other stuff going on.  Just want to convince yourself that the basics of validation do work:

```
class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('username', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(['message' => 'User name cannot be blank'])
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Register'])
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump('Validated');
        }
        return $this->render('user/register.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]);

    }
}

# user/register.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Register Form</h1>
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'novalidate':'novalidate'}}) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice, started over step by step and got it to work, I still never managed to debug the issue, However I think I am a bit more comfortable with it now